# mysql command line not outputting results

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, select, command-line

I'm baffled as to where I'm going wrong with the following mysql command in my bash script to get a SELECT statement out in HTML format.

```
#!/bin/bash

dbhost="localhost"
dbname="unicentaopos"
dbuser="user"
dbpass="pass"

mysql -h $dbhost -u $dbuser -p $dbpass -H -e "SELECT NOW();" $dbname > /home/imperial/.scripts/test.txt
```

Everything is identical to my script, except for the credentials for obvious reasons. I have also tried hard coding the vars into the command - same results.

I cannot see anything wrong with what I've done, but the text file produced just contains mysql usage options:

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.7.25, for Linux (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
Copyright (c) 2000, 2019, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Usage: mysql [OPTIONS] [database]
  -?, --help          Display this help and exit.
  -I, --help          Synonym for -?
etc etc etc etc.....
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Did you specify the host? -h hostname

Comment: Sorry everyone, I'm baffled as to how that hashtag got in there, must have miskeyed something when I copy and pasted. My script does correctly use $dbhost, which is simply localhost - same result.

Comment: We have no idea what your command is after it has done variable expansion. I suggest you use `set -x` to enable debugging echo of the command after it has finished all expansions.

Comment: Sorry I've been away for a while, but still need to solve this! I've edited my question to include my entire script. I tried `set -x` but it just repeats the mysql command back to me, prefixed with a `+`

Answer (score 1):

is the dbhost variable accessed correctly? 
#dbhost -> $dbhost

Comment: Mistake on my part there, please see edited question.